# typecasting forward and backward

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I need to type cast a "Token" type to "obj" and inversely "obj" to "Token".

While I have found the way for the direction from obj to Token I don't know how to do the inverse.

```
typdef int16_t Token;

struct obj{
    Token t;
    operator Token(){return t-tokenBase;}
}
```

The use is to do:

```
(Token)o
```

and have a Token and inversely

```
(obj)t
```

and have an obj

Comment: Provide a constructor for your struct that takes a `Token` as its only argument: `obj::obj(Token t)`

Comment: Why can't I do symmetrically, by defining something like: Token::operator obj(){return *this+tokenBase;}

Comment: Because the language specification says so. (Non-class types have no member operators.)

Comment: But so I would have to use different syntax for the two cases, isn't it ?

Comment: Yap, for the definition of the two conversion methods. However, the constructor I've just mentioned enables you to just "cast" a `Token` to an `obj`. ([demo](http://ideone.com/G8Zsb2).)

Comment: You mean that I can use it as: "(obj)t" instead of "obj(t)"

Comment: Did you read the demo code I just linked?

Comment: Difficult to read and understand ( while short ). You use a syntax where you assign values to variables with no initialization code. Has that any different meaning than initializing them on the beginning ( I guess no ). Thanks any way . I will have to study some things .

Comment: You could at least perceive that I used `(Foo)1337` in `main()`. So yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need a conversion operator to convert obj to Token, but for the other way, you need a special constructor. try this code and it might be more clear to you.

```
typedef int16_t Token;

struct obj{
    Token t;
    obj(Token tt):t(tt){
        std::cout << "special constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    operator Token(){
        std::cout << "conversion operator called" << std::endl;
        return t;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    obj test(13);
    std::cout<< (Token) test<<std::endl; // uses conversion operator
    Token t = 244;
    ((obj)t).print(); // uses constructor
}
```

another more hacky way is to us pointer conversions. This is not really clean code and should be used carefully and when you know what you're doing.

```
typedef int16_t Token;

struct obj{
    Token t;
    void print(){
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    obj test;
    std::cout<< *((Token*) &test)<<std::endl;
    Token t = 244;
    (*((obj*) &t)).print();
}
```

this ugly behaviour can be written in a function generalised like this:

```
template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
Type2& convert2(Type1& a){
    return *((Type2*) &a);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the template fun just for fun. I'm not encouraging you to use this behaviour, but sometimes it might be easier.